# how to create cell go on next page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I create one page that is TableView and this TableView has many cell from this code :

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *animal;
    NSMutableArray *color;
    NSMutableArray *all;
}
@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    animal = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Lion",@"Tiger",@"Dog",@"Cat",@"Sheep",@"Wolf", nil];
    color = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Red",@"Yellow",@"Green",@"Black", nil];

    all = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [all addObjectsFromArray:animal];
    [all addObjectsFromArray:color];
}
```

I want when to click animal cell array go on next page (next page is
selfsame root tableview in other word I want when click animal cell array tableview page refresh and show me information clicked cell)

Comment: do you want to use same UIViewController to display 'list of animal' and 'details of animal' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //if need any condition check here
 YourViewController *YVC = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]]  
 [self.navigationController YourViewController:YVC animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: my friend I want when to click for example cell 1 return same page (first page)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link (it has example for loading a detail view from the table),
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jt0vcrzq4A